# Distribution function that is not absolutely continuous

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, absolute-continuity

> Find, with proof, an example of a distribution function $F$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with absolutely continuous margins or component functions that is not absolutely continuous.

I know that if $F$ is absolutely continuous, its margins are absolutely continuous. Also, $F$ is absolutely continuous if it can be written in the form $\int_{-\infty}^{x_1} \cdots \int_{-\infty}^{x_d} f(z_1,\cdots, z_d) dz_1\cdots dz_d,$ where $f$ is the density of $f$. I also know that random vectors are vectors of random variables. However, I'm not sure how to find a distribution function $F$ with absolutely continuous margins that is not absolutely continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ have a standard normal distribution and $X_i=X$ for $1\leq i \leq n$. Then the distribution function of $(X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ is concentrated on the set $\{(x,x,...,x):x \in \mathbb R\}$ which has Lebesgue measure $0$ so it is not absolutely continuous. But the marginals are normal.

Comment: Can you provide some more justification? I feel this deviates too much from the definition. For instance, why is the distribution function of the random vector $X$ concentrated on the given set? And why does that set having Lebesgue measure $0$ imply it's not absolutely continuous? Also, why are the marginals normal and thus absolutely continuous?

Comment: Supose the joint density exists. Since the  intergal of the density over any set of measure $0$ is $0$ we see that the joint distribution is $0$ at every point! This is absurd, so density cannot exist . The first marginal is nothing but the distribution of $X_1$ which is $N(0,1)$. So it is absolutely continuous. Same thing with all the other marginals.

Comment: thanks! I understand it better now.